# Path to another css from a no-extension file in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have got a project built in Zend-framework V1, where the link to another css file from a no-extensioned file is assigned in this way.

In the header file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/assets/user/css/login.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

But the public folder structure is like the below

**public/assets/user(now this user is a file without any extension)**

and when I open this "user" file I get the following line

```
../../packages/user/public/assets/user
```

I can find the login.css which is under

packages/user/public/assets/user/css/login.css

This is working fine in live but my local is not detecting the correct css.

Any help is highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If file does not exists then request goes trough Zend, so maybe look for this path there? Try Controller `assets`, Action `userAction` or look for similar path in routing table in Zend. Or maybe this user file is just a link (symlink) to folder with this file?

Comment: I think you are correct. It's a symlink thing and not related with Zend. Thanks for your help.